# Can you set a row to false unless a request is posted every 20 seconds in Elixir and Phoenix?

Tags: elixir

If a http post containing address=127.0.0.1&port=1234&heatbeat=1 is not sent to `http://localhost/here` within 15 seconds, then set the server row of the server to active: false.

How do you do that with the Elixir Phoenix Web Framework.

Comment: Edited post to include a more specific question.

Answer (score 3):

You would use a GenServer and using Erlang's `timer` module to send messages to your worker. Since Phoenix is just an OTP app, you can integrate with it like any other OTP lib. Here's a basic example:

```
defmodule URLPoller do
  use GenServer

  @interval_ms 15000

  def start_link(opts) do
    GenServer.start_link __MODULE__, opts, []
  end

  def init(opts) do
    :timer.send_interval @interval_ms, :poll
    {:ok, %{url: Dict.fetch(opts, :url)}}
  end

  def handle_info({:poll, groups}, state) do
    # poll your endpoint
    {:noreply, state}
  end
end
```

Once started, this server will receive the `:poll` message every 15s. You would slot this into your supervision tree so it is restarted on crash.